# Compilation errors in xCode 7 + Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7-beta2

Since I have installed the xCode 7 beta2 + Swift 2.0, I'm getting some errors in my app. For example, I'm getting the following error

> "Cannot invoke 'requestAccessToEntityType' with an argument list of type '(EKEntityType, completion: (Bool, NSError!) -> _)'

in this part of code:

```
eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event,
    completion: {(granted: Bool, error:NSError!) in
            if !granted {
                print("Access to store not granted")
            }
    })
```

Also this error:

> Cannot invoke 'predicateForEventsWithStartDate' with an argument list of type '(NSDate, endDate: NSDate, calendars: [AnyObject])'

in this part of code:

```
calendarsPrueba.addObject(calendarWithName("US Holidays")!)
var predicate2 = eventStore.predicateForEventsWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, calendars: calendarsPrueba as [AnyObject])
```

Do somebody know how to fix this issues? There's no Apple documentation about this

Comment: Did you run the migrator?

Answer (score 2):

Same question as @HAS had - did you run the migrator? Lot of incompatible changes between Swift 1.2 and Swift 2.0. Code must be migrated or manually fixed.

**`requestAccessToEntityType`**

Error ...

> Cannot invoke 'requestAccessToEntityType' with an argument list of
>   type '(EKEntityType, completion: (Bool, NSError!) -> _)'

... is there because your type is `(Bool, NSError!) -> Void` instead of `(Bool, NSError?) -> Void`. Replace `NSError!` with `NSError?` to fix it.

Check documentation, signature is:

```
typealias EKEventStoreRequestAccessCompletionHandler = (Bool, NSError?) -> Void
```

**`predicateForEventsWithStartDate`**

> Cannot invoke 'predicateForEventsWithStartDate' with an argument list
>   of type '(NSDate, endDate: NSDate, calendars: [AnyObject])'

Signature is:

```
func predicateForEventsWithStartDate(_ startDate: NSDate,
  endDate endDate: NSDate,
  calendars calendars: [EKCalendar]?) -> NSPredicate
```

With your `as [AnyObject]` you're trying to pass `[AnyObject]` instead of `[EKCalendar]`. To fix this, declare `calendarsPrueba` as:

```
var calendarsPrueba: [EKCalendar]
```

And do not cast it to `[AnyObject]`.

> Do somebody know how to fix this issues? There's no Apple
>   documentation about this

There is. Always read release notes, where you can find summary of all changes. And then recheck documentation, because as I wrote, you can find many significant changes between Swift 1.2 and Swift 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

this works with Xcode 7 / swift 2:

```
final func addToCalendar(){

    let eventStore = EKEventStore()
    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion: { (granted, error) in
        if !granted {
            // Show alert...
            print("Access not allowed")
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
        else {
            print("Access granted")
            let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
            let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
            event.title = "sample Event " + uuid
            event.startDate = NSDate();
            event.endDate = event.startDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(60*60)
            event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents

            do {
                try eventStore.saveEvent(event,  span: .ThisEvent)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    })
```