# EventKit in Swift not working with Swift 2.0

Tags: macos, swift, eventkit

I am trying to migrate to swift 2.0 but not all of my code is working. I have succed to migrate most of the code but I stillt have troubles using the EventKit. The code below was working fine with swift 1.2. But now I have a Problem

```
import Foundation
import EventKit
import Cocoa

private let _SingletonSharedInstance = EventStore()

class EventStore {
    let eventStore = EKEventStore ()

    class var sharedInstance : EventStore {
        return _SingletonSharedInstance
    }

    init() {
        var sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
        var hasAccess = false

        eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent, completion: { (granted:Bool, error:NSError?) in hasAccess = granted; dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema) })

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
        if (!hasAccess) {
            println("ACCESS", "ACCESS LONG")
            let sharedWorkspace = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
            sharedWorkspace.openFile("/Applications/System Preferences.app")
            exit (0)
        }
    }
}
```

Following line is causing the Problems

```
eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityTypeEvent, completion: { (granted:Bool, error:NSError?) in hasAccess = granted; dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema) })
```

I am getting the error

> cannot invoke "requestAccessToEntityType" with an argument list of type '(EKEEntityType, completion: (Bool, NSError?) -> ())'

I read that using `NSError!` should solve the issue but it did not. 
Any ideas?

Comment: see at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31087340/compilation-errors-in-xcode-7-swift-2-0/33605707#33605707 it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The bool type had changed to ObjCBool and `EKEntityTypeEvent` to `EKEntityType.Event`.

```
import Foundation
import EventKit
import Cocoa

private let _SingletonSharedInstance = EventStore()

class EventStore {
    let eventStore = EKEventStore ()

    class var sharedInstance : EventStore {
        return _SingletonSharedInstance
    }

    init() {
        var sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
        var hasAccess:ObjCBool = false

        eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion: { (granted:ObjCBool, error:NSError?) in hasAccess = granted; dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema) })

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
        if (!hasAccess) {
            println("ACCESS", "ACCESS LONG")
            let sharedWorkspace = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
            sharedWorkspace.openFile("/Applications/System Preferences.app")
            exit (0)
        }
    }
}
```